# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a generic method for paging which I am trying to invoke.
But I am getting a compile time error:
*The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage*

**Method:**

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderedPagedResults<T, TResult, TType>(IQueryable<T> query, int pageNum, int pageSize,
                        Expression<Func<T, TResult>> orderByProperty, bool isAscendingOrder, out int rowsCount,
                        List<KeyValuePair<Expression<Func<T, TType>>, bool>> lstThenByConditions = null)
        {
            if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 20;

            rowsCount = query.Count();

            if (rowsCount <= pageSize || pageNum <= 0) pageNum = 1;

            var excludedRows = (pageNum - 1) * pageSize;

            query = isAscendingOrder ? query.OrderBy(orderByProperty) : query.OrderByDescending(orderByProperty);

            if (lstThenByConditions != null && lstThenByConditions.Any())
            {
                foreach (var thenByProperty in lstThenByConditions)
                {
                    if (!thenByProperty.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<Expression<Func<T, TType>>, bool>))
                        && (typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(query.Expression.Type)))
                    {
                        query = thenByProperty.Value

                            ? (query as IOrderedQueryable<T>).ThenBy(orderByProperty)

                            : (query as IOrderedQueryable<T>).ThenByDescending(orderByProperty);
                    }
                }
            }

            return query.Skip(excludedRows).Take(pageSize);
        }
```

I am trying to invoke this as:

```
var resultset = OrderedPagedResults(employees, pageNum, rowNum,
                                o => o.JoiningDate, isSortAscending, out totalRows);
```

where employees = IQueryable
Due to some reason I am getting this compile time error and I am not able to invoke this.

Any suggestion what I am missing here?

Comment: As a point of style, I would caution you against rewriting parameter `query` in the body of the method. Doing so makes your code harder to debug because now you cannot see both the original and new values without looking back in the stack. Local variables are cheap; use them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler, whilst fairly smart, isn't always able to infer generic types, such as the case here, because there are multiple generic types. How does it know what they are supposed to be? You need to be more explicit:

```
var resultset = OrderedPagedResults<IEnumerable<Employee>, int, int>
(employees, pageNum, rowNum, o => o.JoiningDate, isSortAscending, out totalRows);
```

(I'm guessing at the types there)

Eric Lippert has a great explanation of this somewhere, but I can't recall where it is.

Comment: Are you thinking of this video? http://ericlippert.com/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three/

Comment: @EricLippert looks like the video is gone and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681478/complement-higher-order-function-in-c-sharp) could benefit from the explanation

Answer (score 3):

Stuart Grassie's answer is correct but omits the detail which explains why you are getting the error.  **In your example, from which argument is the compiler supposed to deduce the type argument you intended for type parameter `TType`**?

I can't find any such argument; the compiler cannot either, and therefore you have not given it enough information from which to infer the type.